# Bug : popup appears behind content in Area51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When I hover over my name in the header in Area51, the popup appears behind the site content area as shown:
[image]
The bug appears when using Google Chrome or Firefox 4 in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We increased the z-index on the popup, so this is fixed now. Thanks for the report.